# How can I find API Key and where do I use it?

Tags: android, api-key

I have two questions:

1. I want to find apiKey and I find MD5 code but when I copy MD5 in sign up key in Google, writes this is wrong but I copy MD5 of cmd. I get apiKey before but now Googlewrites this wrong!! Is it possible this problem is for I get apikey before? but I get apikey before for debug no final version.
2. When I find apiKey, How can I get final version? Should I select export ? Where I use apiKey? Do I use this in apikey of map in layout folder of my program?

Comment: Had you read the tutorial from [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)?

Comment: Yes. I read and i find MD5 code but google says, this is wrong!!

Answer (score 1):

Steps to generate apiKey for release:
1. Build Keystore - from eclipse > right click on project and then android tools > Export Signed Application Package
2. Open cmd and navigate to the bin folder of jre. You should have something like this in cmd (depending on the location where you have the jre installed):

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin >
```

Now write the following cmd

```
keytool -v -list -alias <your alias> -keystore <path to keystore>
```

where **< your alias >** will be replaced with the alias used when creating the keystore.
**< path to keystore >** is the location where you saved the keystore.

eg. : keytool -v -list -alias alias_name -keystore e:\name.keystore

This is the way it worked for me every time.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure is MD5 and not SHA1? The -v is used to return the MD5 code, among the SHA1 if having JRE 7.

Comment: If it askes for your password we are on the right way.  Cmd is not blocked, enter your password even nothing changes in cmd, and after  press enter. You should get the codes

Comment: Thank. I find apikey but apikey get me google, is like previously api!! now what should i do?? why my apk file that create by this way not show?

Comment: also what is usefullness of find apikey for final version? i dont use apikey nowhere of my program!!

Comment: if you are using google maps in your app, then you will need the apiKey. If you don't use google maps, then you can let this problem for later :)

Comment: I use google map and i find apiKey but now the program not show map. Why? i find api key but this is reduplicative like apikey that i find before!

Comment: When using google maps, you have to apiKeys, one for debug and another for release. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview)

Comment: I read this before, but i find apiKey for release with your way and the program not shows map! and don't know Why? and apiKey that i find is like apikey of debug version!